# Can youtube uploader block video from being played in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I would like to play youtube videos in an IOS app using youtube API.  Can a video's uploader block the video from being played in an IOS app?

Comment: If you mean to say will youtube will block your app playing some videos then no.
Else please elaborate more on the question

Comment: No I mean the video's uploader

Comment: No can not as long as you are using YouTube apis

Comment: There can be some restrictions like age, regions that might be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, youtube video can be blocked from being played in IOS apps at the discretion of the content uploader.

https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html